# How to load other static elements before FutureBuilder finishes fetching items

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

I would like to load static elements like `bottom navigation bar` before `FutureBuilder` will be loaded.  So it should looks like this. When we enter the new screen,
`CircularProgressIndicator` is shown in the middle and other elements like bottom navigation is already shown.
Could you tell me how can I achieve this?
Here is my code:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:package/constants/AppConstants.dart';
import 'package:package/util/HttpActions.dart';

import 'BottomAppBar.dart';
import 'FAB.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String jwt;

  const HomePage(this.jwt);

  @override
  _HomePage createState() => _HomePage();

  factory HomePage.fromBase64(String jwt) => HomePage(jwt);
}

class _HomePage extends State<HomePage> {
  late final String jwt;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    jwt = widget.jwt;
  }

  final uri = Uri.http(
      AppConstants.BASE_URL,
      AppConstants.SOME_URL,
      {'email': 'some.mail@gmail.com'}); // TODO change to proper link

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder(
              future: http.get(
                uri,
                headers: {
                  HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader:
                      HttpActions.APPLICATION_JSON_HEADER,
                  HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: jwt
                },
              ),
              builder: (context, snapshot) => snapshot.hasData
                  ? Scaffold(
                      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFEF9F9FC),
                      floatingActionButtonLocation:
                          FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
                      floatingActionButton: buildFAB(),
                      bottomNavigationBar: BuildBottomAppBar(),
                    )
                  : snapshot.hasError
                      ? Text("An error occurred")
                      : CircularProgressIndicator()),
        ),
      );
}
```

Now if you see navigation bottom bar is loaded when snaphost has data.
Is there any way to make something like column, so I will have static item, static item, future builder, static item (which is `nav bottom bar`)

I want to achieve effect like this:
[desired effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLo1o.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first widget will be the Scaffold, with the bottom navigation bar and inside the body add the Future Builder

Something like this:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:package/constants/AppConstants.dart';
import 'package:package/util/HttpActions.dart';

import 'BottomAppBar.dart';
import 'FAB.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String jwt;

  const HomePage(this.jwt);

  @override
  _HomePage createState() => _HomePage();

  factory HomePage.fromBase64(String jwt) => HomePage(jwt);
}

class _HomePage extends State<HomePage> {
  late final String jwt;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    jwt = widget.jwt;
  }

  final uri = Uri.http(
      AppConstants.BASE_URL,
      AppConstants.SOME_URL,
      {'email': 'some.mail@gmail.com'}); // TODO change to proper link

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) 
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFEF9F9FC),
      floatingActionButtonLocation:
         FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      floatingActionButton: buildFAB(),
      bottomNavigationBar: BuildBottomAppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder(
              future: http.get(
                uri,
                headers: {
                  HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader:
                      HttpActions.APPLICATION_JSON_HEADER,
                  HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: jwt
                },
              ),
              builder: (context, snapshot) => snapshot.hasData
                  ? widgetWithYourData
                  : snapshot.hasError
                      ? Text("An error occurred")
                      : CircularProgressIndicator()),
      ),
    )
}
```